# When I compile master branch, it shows up changes from my feature branch?

Tags: git

I am having a weird problem.
I have 2 branches, master M and my feature branch F.
Whenever I do fresh cloning of a repository X, it is cloned and I am put in master (obvious). It does not contain code form my feature branch F. However, when I compile master, I can see changes from my feature branch F. I have tried clean build multiple times. What is messing up?

Comment: can you share you github link?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! as well as your github or gitlab link to the remote repo, please can you add the git clone command you ran?

Comment: “It does not contain code form my feature branch F. However, when I compile master, I can see changes from my feature branch F” Then the first sentence is evidently false. Is the question how to _see_ branch F?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you checkout the branch you want to work on.

```
$git checkout <BRANCH>
```

You can also check your active branch by putting this code in .bashrc

```
# Show git branch name
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() 
{
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\ 
[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```